# Kernel, row space and orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra

The set of solutions of $Ax=0$ i.e. kernel or null space of $A$ is perpendicular to each row of A. But why is the kernel of $A$ perpendicular to the row space of it? In other words why is it perpendicular to
$$
c_1A_1+\cdots+c_mA_m
$$
where $c_l,\ldots,c_m$ are numbers and $A_1,\ldots,A_m$ are row vectors of $A$? As the second question, is $ker(A)$ perpendicular to the column space of $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, assuming you've seen the formulation of orthogonality as a dot product, we assume (At least you seem comfortable assuming) that $A_i \cdot v= 0$ for every $v$ in the kernel and $1 \leq i \leq m$. Now let $v$ be any element of the kernel then we simply need check

$$(c_1A_1 + ... c_mA_m)\cdot v = 0$$

But this is simply an immediate application of the dot products algebraic properties given the assumptions. (Note more generally this shows for any $S$ subset of a vector space, the set $S^\perp$ of vectors perpendicular to it is a subspace).

As to your second question, in general it cannot be true because the column space lies in a different dimensional space unless the matrix is square. Of course, it's not even true for square matrices.

Answer (score 3):

The row space of $A$ is the collection of linearly independent vectors that span the rows of $A$. Thus, these vectors are in $\mathbb{R^n}$. Now you have the null space or kernel is the set of all vectors such that $A\textbf{x}=0$, note here the vectors that span the row space of $A$ are row vectors of $A$ and are in $\mathbb{R^m}$. Hence, they perpendicular to the set of solutions for the null space.

The main idea is just that the row vectors of $A$ determine the matrix. Although you may not know which ones are in the row space of $A$ they still are there.